# Importar CSV a Google Sheets

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, importación

verán después de tanto investigar encontré un script para importar archivos csv desde drive a Google Sheets y funciona sin problemas, pero cuando le programo un trigger para ejecurse a una hora en concreto este no funciona, simplemente se detiene en el script cuando ingresa al arreglo.

He leído que se tiene que abrir primero la hoja de calculo en el servidor, pero no entiendo bien como hacerlo.

Este es el código que uso:

```
function importData() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var name = "Index";
  //var newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);

  var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('1eLS8Gxbo2pVPWBAZdXgxZjs6dZduWWZU'); // reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved
  var fi = fSource.getFilesByName('CLI_01B01'); // latest report file
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1SihaH0frPYaMmNdbM5yBHbW6Mm07AMgFdbjdglsr3uQ'); // data_sheet_id = id of spreadsheet that holds the data to be updated with new report data


  //Insertamos hoja para no dejar vació el documento
  spreadsheet.insertSheet('Index'); 
  //Eliminamos hoja CLI
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('CLI'), true);
  spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();


  //Importamos hoja CLI
  if ( fi.hasNext() ) { // proceed if "report.csv" file exists in the reports folder
    var file = fi.next();
    var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function
    var newsheet = ss.insertSheet('CLI'); // create a 'NEWDATA' sheet to store imported data
    // loop through csv data array and insert (append) as rows into 'NEWDATA' sheet
    for ( var i=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i++ ) {
      newsheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }

    /*
    ** report data is now in 'NEWDATA' sheet in the spreadsheet - process it as needed,
    ** then delete 'NEWDATA' sheet using ss.deleteSheet(newsheet)
    */
    // rename the report.csv file so it is not processed on next scheduled run
    // file.setName("report-"+(new Date().toString())+".csv"); // Esto renombrará el archivo original.

  }
  //Eliminamos hoja Index
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Index'), true);
  spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();

};
```

Agradeceré su ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a [es.so]. Agrega el error textual indicado en la página de ejecuciones o que se te ha enviado por correo electrónico.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, el error que me sale es este "Exception: Error de servicio: Hojas de cálculo"; como indiqué todo funciona bien al ejecutar manualmente pero con un trigger de tiempo es donde se produce ese error y he leído que se tiene que abrir en el servidor y allí viene el problema.

Comment: Falta indicar el número de línea en el que ocurre el error.Por favor edita laa pregunta para agrear esos datos.

Comment: Por favor lee [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Hola, lo he solucionado, el problema era al momento que se ejecuta el trigger no cuando se ejecuta con el archivo abierto, no encontraba la hoja ya que no había especificado la ruta completa sino que hacía referencia a la hoja activa(cuando no había dicha cosa).
Solo he tenido que asignar el mismo valor de "ss" a "spreadsheet", como también podía haber reemplazado la "spreadsheet -> ss". 
Bueno espero que le sirva a quien le suceda lo mismo. Gracias por todo.

Comment: Estas publicando la respuesta como comentario. Agrégala como respuesta (abajo hay una caja de texto con el título "Tu Repuesta" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo he solucionado, el problema era al momento que se ejecuta el trigger no cuando se ejecuta con el archivo abierto, no encontraba la hoja ya que no había especificado la ruta completa sino que hacía referencia a la hoja activa(cuando no había dicha cosa). 
Solo he tenido que asignar el mismo valor de "ss" a "spreadsheet", como también podía haber reemplazado la "spreadsheet -> ss". Bueno espero que le sirva a quien le suceda lo mismo. Gracias por todo.

```
var spreadsheet = ss
```